# How is electric field inside any closed conductor always zero?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

I mean how is electric field in the empty space of a closed conductor due to any external electric field zero always?

Answer (score 4):

A material is a conductor if it contains electric charges that are easy to move. In a metal, for example, the electrons are only loosely bound to the metal atoms, so they can be moved by applying an electric field or a battery.

Now, if there is no electric field, The electrons will be attracted to nearby atoms, so the positive and negative charges will stay near each other, resulting in no internal electric field. If an external field is applied, electrons will move in response. Now, since the electrons moved and are not in the same place as the protons anymore, the metal itself gains an internal electric field that points in the opposite direction as the applied field. The electrons will continue to move until these two fields exactly cancel.

In both cases, the total electric field inside the conductor vanishes quickly.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is only true for *perfect* conductors (like superconductors), which suggests:

1. There are always sufficient amount of free charges.
2. The free charges can move without resistance.

If the electric field is non-zero inside a conductor, the positive and negative charges would split and move, until the electric field is fully cancelled out.

Answer (score 0):

For an electric field to exist it must have a start point and termination point (may be infinity) inside a conductor the charges are uniformly arranged throughout the surface this a start point might be found. However infinity or a negative potential can not be obtained. Thus no electric field.

Answer (score -1):

There is a lot of depth to this situation, but here are the basics:
Gauss' Law of Electrostatics states that the divergence in the electrical field is proportional to the internal charge for a closed surface. What does that really mean? It means that the amount of flux from the field, (the amount of outward flow in the image) depends on the charge inside of a closed surface. In a closed conductor, there is no internal charge, so Gauss's Law states that the E field must be 0.

[image]

Comment: Note how the lines stem from the charges. This is essentially Gauss's Law; that charges cause divergence (sinks/sources) in the field. Because there are no charges in the field, there cannot be any "flow" in the field of that area.

Comment: Gauss' Law does not prohibit a field inside of a conductor.  It says that the integral of the flux must be zero.